# Final temperature of mixing two different mass flows of the same gas in a different temperature and pressure

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, ideal-gas, flow

I've forgotten most of the terms involved in thermodynamics, so pardon me for using layman terms.

I have a gas turbine and a wastegate that bypasses the turbine. The vessel in which the gas flows is considered solid. I'm trying to calculate the temperature of the gas mix produced (exhaust gas, can be considered ideal gas or air) when the gas coming trough the turbine meets the gas going trough the bypass.

I've got the temperatures,pressures and mass flow rates before and after the turbine. I've tried calculating this trough mass-temperature average (not sure if that's the correct name) substituting mass-flow-rate for mass, but I'm not sure if that is the right way.

I'm also a bit unsure about the pressure of the bypassed mass flow. Specifically, I'm not sure if the pressure should be considered already equalized (then I'm mixing two flows with the same pressure) when mixing the flows, or are the pressures considered to equalize on the meeting point (then I'm mixing two different pressures).

Comment: Correct me if I misunderstand, but it seems like you are over complicating. You are mixing gas after the turbine (you know temperature and mass flow rate) with gas from the bypass (you know the temperature and mass flow rate). You are mixing two gases with known flowrates and temperatures. What's the difficulty?

Comment: What you did for the temperatures is correct, assuming that you used the enthalpies.  For the pressures, you can use the macroscopic mechanical energy balance equation for multiple inlets and outlets presented in Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot, Transport Phenomena, Chapter 8.

Comment: I used the equation from [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/203547/dynamic-response-of-temperature-change-when-identical-fluids-flowing-mix-togethe) to calculate the temperature. Is that wrong?

Comment: No.  It is correct.